# jump on specific location in binary file

Tags: java, android, file-io

I have a binary file which contains image.i have to jump on different locations in file to read the image file. So far i am using mark and reset methods but these are not helping me as i want.
please somebody help me about that i,ll be really thankful.and i am using Input Stream to read the file.

Comment: Could you remove the code part for your first sentence? This way, your question will be more easy to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [java.io.RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to do this. The methods [seek(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) and [getFilePointer()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getFilePointer()) will help to jump to different offsets in the file and come back to original offsets:

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("/my/image/file", "rw");

// read some data.

long positionToJump = 10L;

long origPos = f.getFilePointer(); // store the original position

f.seek(positionToJump);
// now you are at position 10, start reading from here.

// go back to original position
f.seek(origPos);
```

Answer (score 2):

Android seems to have [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), have you tried it?

Comment: can i use it in input Stream?

Comment: If you already have FileInputStream (not generic InputStream!), you can use getChannel() method to get FileChannel. But opening new RandomAccessFile is simpler.

Comment: @sajjoo - [`FileInputStream`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html) provides a `getChannel()` method.

Comment: Actually i am using 3 input stream.... inputStream -> CountingInputstream -> SwappedInputstream. and i am developing an application for android. 

InputStream iStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.map);

so i need jumping on different addresses or if i can go back to start of file some how in stream.

Comment: The InputStream interface doesn't provide ways to seek to certain positions, because it's meant to abstract away a sequential input stream, and certain implementations might not support that (think about a socket, for example). So if you want to seek, you need a more specialized class: FileInputStream's getChannel(), a RandomAccessFile, or some other class that allows seeking.

Looking at the android API (I'm not familiar with it, just with Java), you could potentially use Resources.openRawResourceFd() and build a FileInputStream from the returned AssetFileDescriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7 you can use `java.nio.file.Files` and `SeekableByteChannel`

```
byte[] getRandomAccessResults(Path filePath, long offset) throws IOException
{
    try (SeekableByteChannel byte_channel = java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(filePath, StandardOpenOption.READ))
    {
        ByteBuffer byte_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
        byte_channel.position(offset);
        byte_channel.read(byte_buffer);
        return byte_buffer.array();
    }
}
```