# How to start reading a file at specific position?

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

First of all I have a couple hours experience with Java so, If its a bit simple question, sorry about that.

Now, I want to read a file but I dont want to start at the beginning of file instead I want to skip first 1024 bytes and than start reading. Is there a way to do that ? I realized that RandomAccessFile  might be useful but I'm not sure.

```
try {
     FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(fName);
       // skip 1024 bytes somehow and start reading .
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You could just read 1024 bytes and then do your thing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeap its a way to handle, but isnt it a kind of useless ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis btw after 1024 bytes, sometimes I need to skip part of file so it would be better if I learn to do that

Comment: Related: if it's a binary file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624352/jump-on-specific-location-in-binary-file; if it's a text file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102703/read-text-file-from-position-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the [`FileInputStream.skip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip%28long%29) method to seek to the point you want and then begin reading from that point. There is more information in the javadocs about `FileInputStream` that you might find interesting.

Comment: @dcolish by the way my file is binary .It causes any problem ?

Comment: @TheGost: not at all: "[FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data."

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method like skipBytes() here

```
/**
 * Read count bytes from the InputStream to "/dev/null".
 * Return true if count bytes read, false otherwise.
 * 
 * @param is
 *          The InputStream to read.
 * @param count
 *          The count of bytes to drop.
 */
private static boolean skipBytes(
    java.io.InputStream is, int count) {
  byte[] buff = new byte[count];
  /*
   * offset could be used in "is.read" as the second arg
   */
  try {
    int r = is.read(buff, 0, count);
    return r == count;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return false;
}
```